# Count 20 second in php ajax loop and return results

Tags: php, ajax

I have an php and ajax script..

```
         $.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
               if(response == 0){
                $('.fetchresults').show();
                $('.fetchresults').html('<button type="button" class="btn close">x</button>No new podcast posts added.</div>');           
                $('.fetchresults').fadeIn('fast');
                } else {
                $('.fetchresults').show();
                $('.fetchresults').html('<button type="button" class="btn close">x</button>' + response + ' new podcasts posts added.</div>');            
                $('.fetchresults').fadeIn('fast');

                } 
           });
```

and in php i am getting results from table

```
          $podcast_items = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM " . $table_spp_podcast );
```

and then in foreach loop fetch results and then insert into wordpress posts.

Sometime there too many records in the table and server execution time out and some time go stuck.

All i want to count 20 second and then return ajax results and then recall ajax automatically....

Is that possible?

Comment: So I assume that your maximum script execution time on the server is 20 sec., right. Why not processing your table in batches of some fixed size which will be definitely processed under 20 sec. and then process each batch one after another?

Comment: Can you explain more in coding ?